# How can I get all instances at once in Alloy* analyzer?

Tags: jar, alloy

I use high order logic in my als file, and I want to get all instances at once, so I try to use Alloy Api in a java file (use alloy4.2 jar to compile and run), but it does not work (cannot deal with high order logic).

Is there any Alloy* Api like Alloy Api? if not, is there some other methods?